# Программа которые делает из введенных данных список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно написать программу, которая будет делать список из введенных пользователем цифры в список.
Пробовал что такое:

```
inputt = input("Введите число")

listik = [inputt]
print(listik)
```

но надо что бы выводилось что то такое:

```
listik = [типо введенные пользователем данные без кавычек]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inputt = input("Введите число")
listik = inputt.split()
print(listik)
```

Answer (score 1):

`input` возвращает строку, а вам нужно работать с числами. Строку превратить в число можно с помощью `int`

```
inputt = int(input("Введите число"))
```

если на вход подаётся такая строка `"0 1 2"` то её надо разделить по пробелу, и каждый элемент превратит в число

```
inputt = input("Введите число")

listik = [int(el) for el in inputt.split()]
```